# resize image based on query string

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel. I want to resize images and create thumbnail based on query string.

For example, if someone requests `example.com/1.jpg?width=120` or `example.com/anything/1.jpg?width=120`, the original image must change to the new resized image.

In fact, all I want is the routing system for image files like `.jpg` and `.png` where has a query string.

is there any way in PHP or Laravel to get all request for images files with query string and manipulate it?

---

Update:
I tested @iftikhar-uddin answer.
it work for single request. like when i request this url directly `example.com/anything/1.jpg?width=120` in browser.

but i want to get all images and manipulate them when page is loading.

example :
i have multiple html tag like this `<img src="/anything/1.jpg?width=120">`
and when page is loading, i want to get all images and manipulate them by the size of query string.

**what i did before ?**
currently i wrote a class for this. but the problem is i can't find original directory of images in some case.
in my class :
1- i get image source and size in image tag like this `<img src="{{class::cache($model->image, 'small')}}">`

2- then i resize image based on size in my class (with [image.intervention.io](http://image.intervention.io)).

3- but in some case (like when i'm using lfm package) the route of image and the real directory are different. so i get error when i want resize image based on source.(the directory is '/public/share/image.jpg' but route is 'laravel-filemanager/share/image.jpg')

for that reason, i'm searching for a way to get images by url when page is loading, not by source we insert in image tag. i think this way must be much easier.

Comment: did you tried my answer?

Comment: not yet actually. i'll let you know if i tested. right now i'm looking for a method to create thumbnail system and your answer was helpful. but i want something a little different.

Comment: Update your question what exactly do you need? And If the answer is helpful consider accepting it so that other people can benefit from this.

Comment: actually i'm on Vacation and I do not have access to my codes. i'm researching right now. In the next two days I will test the solutions. thanks for your reply. I will share the result with you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tips 1:**

http://image.intervention.io/

> Intervention Image is an open source PHP image handling and
>   manipulation library. It provides an easier and expressive way to
>   create, edit, and compose images and supports currently the two most
>   common image processing libraries GD Library and Imagick.

```
public Intervention\Image\Image resize (integer $width, integer $height, [Closure $callback])

  Resizes current image based on given width and/or height. 
  To constrain the resize command, pass an optional Closure callback as the third parameter.



   // create instance
   $img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg')

   // resize image to fixed size
   $img->resize(300, 200);

   // resize only the width of the image
   $img->resize(300, null);

   // resize only the height of the image
   $img->resize(null, 200);

   // resize the image to a width of 300 and constrain aspect ratio (auto height)
   $img->resize(300, null, function ($constraint) {
      $constraint->aspectRatio();
   });

   // resize the image to a height of 200 and constrain aspect ratio (auto width)
   $img->resize(null, 200, function ($constraint) {
      $constraint->aspectRatio();
   });

// prevent possible upsizing
$img->resize(null, 400, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
    $constraint->upsize();
});
```

**Tips2:**

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php Using PHP functions

Answer (score 0):

Install [Image intervention](http://image.intervention.io/) first

Then in your controller do something like this:

```
if($request->hasFile('image')) {

    $image       = $request->file('image');
    $filename    = $image->getClientOriginalName();

    $width = $request->input('width');
    $height = $request->input('height');

    $image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());              
    $image_resize->resize($width, $height );
    $image_resize->save(public_path('YourImagesPath' .$filename));

}
```